# Understanding a custom sort comparator - How to know what a true return means

Tags: c++

I came across this sort comparator for a vector `std::vector<foo>`

```
bool comp(foo& x, foo& y) 
{
    return x.a < y.a;
}
```

Can someone explain what this does ? Does this mean that if a function returns false. foo x will be on the top and y at the bottom. Basically I am trying to understand is how do i know which element gets to be on the top ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a vector composing of student records like name, age, score. Now you want to sort the vector according to name of students so you pass a custom compare  function to the pre-defined sort function which will sort according to the name of student which will look like.

```
bool comp(foo& x, foo& y) 
{
    return x.name < y.name;
}
```

so, it covers on what it does then lets come to second part of your question.
If name in x is alphabetically smaller than y, then it will return a true and x records will come before y record, else vice versa.